# AspectJ type pattern for all types with a method with an attribute?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Currently I have the standard one:

```
@DeclareParents(value = "(@moody.MyAttribute *)", defaultImpl = MoodyImpl.class)
```

This will add my interface+implementation to any class with `@MyAttribute`

I would like to do this for all classes that have this attribute AND/OR have a method with that attribute.

So this class should also get my interface+implementation:

```
class MyClass {
  @MyAttribute
  public void test()
  {
  }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because both `@DeclareParents` and the newer `@DeclareMixin` need class name specifications in their `value` parameter. If I were you I would refactor my annotation so as to only be applicable to classes, not methods, and then my code to move all annotations to classes as well.

One more option if you absolutely want to stay on your path: Since AspectJ 1.8.2 there is a new [annotation processing feature](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-182.html). You might want to explore that one and create an annotation processor creating an ITD aspect for each affected class with annotated methods.

---

**Update:** I have just remembered a non-standard compiler option `-XhasMember` which you can use:

```
ajc -X

AspectJ Compiler 1.8.2 non-standard options:
    (...)
    -XhasMember         allow hasmethod() and hasfield type patterns in
                        declare parents and declare @type
    (...)
```

**Caveat:** It does not seem to work with @AspectJ syntax, i.e. you cannot use annotation-style `@DeclareParents` but have to use native AspectJ syntax `declare parents`. The default interface implementation is also done differently, i.e. via ITD in the aspect, there is no need for a specific implementation class.

Here is a compileable, fully self-consistent code sample:

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface MyAttribute {}
```

**Interface to be implemented via ITD:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface Moody {
    public void sayHelloTo(String name);
}
```

**Sample classes with(out) marker annotation:**

Class `Foo` has the annotation at class level, `Bar` at method level and `Zot` has no annotation at all.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

@MyAttribute
public class Foo {
    public static void foo() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Bar {
    @MyAttribute
    public static void bar() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Zot {
    public static void zot() {}
}
```

**Driver application:**

For demonstration purposes, the application checks for the existence of a method `sayHelloTo(String)` via reflection.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method;
        try {
            method = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloTo", String.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            method = null;
        }
        System.out.println("Foo: " + method);

        try {
            method = Bar.class.getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloTo", String.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            method = null;
        }
        System.out.println("Bar: " + method);

        try {
            method = Zot.class.getDeclaredMethod("sayHelloTo", String.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            method = null;
        }
        System.out.println("Zot: " + method);
    }
}
```

**Console output (without aspect):**

```
Foo: null
Bar: null
Zot: null
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Moody;
import de.scrum_master.app.MyAttribute;

public aspect ITDAspect {
    declare parents : @MyAttribute * implements Moody;
    declare parents : hasmethod(@MyAttribute * *(..)) implements Moody;

    public void Moody.sayHelloTo(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

**Console output (with aspect):**

```
Foo: public void de.scrum_master.app.Foo.sayHelloTo(java.lang.String)
Bar: public void de.scrum_master.app.Bar.sayHelloTo(java.lang.String)
Zot: null
```

Voilà! We have successfully added the interface including its default implementation to `Bar` which does not have class-level annotation, but a method-level one.

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks for your other option, appreciate it! In my case it happens to be possible to refactor the annotations and create new ones for my classes, I found that to be better for usability in my case.

Comment: Please check out my updated answer. I found exactly the solution you were asking about, even though you had accepted my old answer earlier. I think the new solution is even better and does not require an annotation processing stage during the build process.