# AspectJ advice on method of a class that has a field

Tags: aspectj

I want to write an around advice to set a correlation-id into MDC before the invocation of proceed() and return the old value after it. Here is how far I got:

```java
public aspect CorrelationIdAspect
{
    private pointcut notPrivateMethod() :
        execution(!private * *(..));
    
    private pointcut methodWithContract(Contract contract) :
        execution( * *.*(Contract, ..)) && args(contract, ..);
    
    Object around(Contract contract) : methodWithContract(contract) && notPrivateMethod()
    {
        String oldCorrelationId = MDC.get(Constants.CORRELATION_ID);
        try
        {
            String id = contract.getId().toString();
            MDC.put(Constants.CORRELATION_ID, id);
            Object result = proceed(contract);
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            MDC.put(Constants.CORRELATION_ID, oldCorrelationId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want that this advice should only be applied to classes that have a field of type

> org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

because - obviously - a class that has no logger doesn't need to have the correlation id set and restored. Has anybody an idea how that can be accomplished?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @dreamcrash `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getFormatterLogger()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use compiler option `-XhasMember` (see also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780171/1082681)), to be found in Eclipse here:

[image: Eclipse AspectJ compiler option "Has Member"]

Then you

1. add a marker interface to your aspect,
2. use ITD in order to declare that each class having a `static Logger` field ought to implement that interface and
3. match on the marker interface and all its implementing classes:

```java
public aspect CorrelationIdAspect {
  // 1. marker interface 
  private interface HasLogger {}

  // 2. use ITD in order to declare that each class having a
  // 'static Logger' field ought to implement that interface
  declare parents :
    hasfield(static Logger *) implements HasLogger;

  private pointcut notPrivateMethod() :
    execution(!private * *(..));

  // 3. match on the marker interface and all its implementing classes
  private pointcut hasLogger() :
    within(HasLogger+);

  private pointcut methodWithContract(Contract contract) :
    execution(* *(Contract, ..)) && args(contract, ..);

  Object around(Contract contract) :
    methodWithContract(contract) && notPrivateMethod() && hasLogger()
  {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    return proceed(contract);
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the solution, many thanks! If you want to set this option in pom: in the `<configuration>` of the `<aspectj-maven-plugin>` add this: `<XhasMember>true</XhasMember>`